# Firestore query: search in array of objects for an object with specific value (nested structure)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database

I have a nested structure in my Firebase and I'm trying to get the CollectionGroup of guides with specific name.

Structure looks like this:

```
DOCUMENT: { dives : [ {guide: { firstName: 'Jhonny' } } ] }
```

Image with the structure of my database is attached:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUkNE.jpg)

My code is below:

```
const customerActivitiesQuery = query(collectionGroup(db, 'activities'),
where('dives', 'array-contains', { guide: { firstName: 'Johnny' } }))
```

Is there any chance to do this, or it is completely not possible with Firebase and I have to change the structure of my base?

**UPD.** I've already understood that there should be an exact match in structure and values between two objects, to have this working.

However, I've tried make a full match, but it did not help. Then I made a request less nested for testing purposes, but I still receive nothing from my database. Here is my simplified fetch request:

```
query(collectionGroup(db, 'activities'),
where('dives', 'array-contains', { boat: "Deluna" }))
```

However it works with simple strings like `where('dives', 'array-contains', 'Jhonny')`, but I definitely know that it possible to get docs via objects.

Index in console is set, no errors in this part.

What I’m doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `array-contains` operator perform an exact equality check. So if your `dives` array contains an object that is exactly `{guide: { firstName: 'Jhonny' } }`, the operation will work.

The tricky bit here is that the equality check is performed on the binary gRPC data, which means that on that level it has to be the exact same value. But if they are indeed the same, the `array-contains` operation will work.

---

The more common case is that you have a subset of the fields in the array, and the `array-contains` operator is not made for that case.

The common workaround for that is to create an additional field with just the values you want to query on. For example:

```
dives_guide_firstnames: ["Jhonny"]
```

With that additional field, you can then query:

```
where('dives_guide_firstnames', 'array-contains', 'Johnny')
```

---

Note: you have a typo in `Jhonny` in the data structure, but I'm going to assume that is a typo in the question and not in the actual data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanations, now it becomes more clear. However, I've tried to make an exact match with object and make a new query, but it still not working. Then I have tried to make a request more simple for testing purposes, but I still receive nothing from my database:   

 `const customerActivitiesQuery = query(collectionGroup(db, 'activities'),
   where('dives', 'array-contains', { boat: "Deluna" }))`

What I’m doing wrong?

Comment: The structure you showed in your question cannot be queried for just the boat. You'l have to implement the workaround I described.